# Screen flicker since new RAM installation

Tags: display, memory

My work PC was upgraded by the tech guys (RAM only) and ever since my screen has been flickering but they do not know why this has happened and have yet to fix it.
Does anyone have any ideas as to the problem as using the PC is causing me to get headaches and hurting my eyes!

Comment: I don't know how much you are allowed to do at work without IT's approval but try taking out one of the sticks of RAM and see if it goes away. Also try testing the RAM with memtest, most manufacturers have built in memory diagnostics if you don't have a blanks cd or thumb drive. If RAM is the ONLY thing that has changed then it is your most likely culprit.

Answer (score 2):

All I can say is check the refresh rate of the monitor in the video settings. Make it as high as you can. You may need to install a specific monitor driver to allow for higher refresh rates.

If that does not work, call IT back in and make them figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't think that a ram upgrade would cause video flickering, though if it is an integrated graphics chip it might since that would share system ram. If that is the case, maybe it is the wrong type of ram for the computer, they have different speeds that they run at and usually the faster one downclocks to match the slower one, but it's possible that it could cause problems.

Maybe for a start you could check to see what the old and the new ram are and see if they match, then maybe try each one individually and see if you still have a problem, if your old one works fine and the new one flickers, then it's probably a bad stick of ram. If they both work on their own and they match, maybe you are overloading your motherboard with too much ram.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the monitor cable is correctly seated on both ends.  Check for damage to any pins on the monitor cable.  Assuming you don't have onboard video, you may also want to have the IT people check to see that the video card is correctly seated and that all of its internal cables are connected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that a Electro Static Discharge occurred by the dude working on your memory that's caused a little bit of damage to your video card. That's kind of rare, but it can happen. I'd actually try using a different monitor for a little, maybe switch with a coworker for the day? Alternatively, if you could replace your video card, that'd help. Of course, before doing any of this, you may wanna make sure your cables are all connected tight.

It doesn't sound like a software problem, but never say never.. You could toy with running on a Live Linux CD for a bit, if it does it while on that, then it's at least definitely hardware.

Heck, maybe your cell phone's causing some interference??

Anyway, just isolate and rule-out stuff.. That's the only way in my books.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. Luckily a BIOS update did the trick (but it might be that this also resets the bios to the defaults, and that that was the solution).

Answer (score 0):

If the Ram Isn't running at the intended frequency or voltage it can cause tearing...take the ram out..re seat it go into the bios and chose the xmp profile of the ram.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that the new ram was clocked at 2666mhz and my the motherboard on my laptop only supported 2400mhz I swapped the ram and nw it works just fine.